# Gibbs free energy modification after finishing NEB?

Tags: vasp, transition-state, free-energy

I have finished the NEB calculation, but it seems all the energy I got is Internal energy instead of Gibbs free energy, so do I need to do Gibbs free energy modification? Is there any standard procedure for it?

Comment: I'm not familiar with VASP but in Gaussian there is a standard way to calculate this for a single molecule by performing a frequency calculation. See https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=https://www.cup.uni-muenchen.de/ch/compchem/G98thermo.pdf&ved=2ahUKEwjfn5mK_qr3AhX-GDQIHRg0DgwQFnoECAcQAQ&usg=AOvVaw27_k8PL8ey7DbFmC4pKrBm

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get the Gibbs Free energy from the internal energy, you have to consider the configurational entropy. I anticipate you need the Gibbs Free energy to calculate the activation barrier as a function of the temperature. There are two ways to calculate the activation barrier as a function of temperature, namely, molecular dynamics, and NEB followed by kinetic Monte Carlo. Details of these methods can be found in section 4 of this [review](https://www.annualreviews.org/doi/abs/10.1146/annurev-matsci-081420-041617).

Answer (score 4):

I think the first question you have to ask is whether you can get an accurate free energy for your reaction barrier in VASP. If you have a reaction with a small molecule on an oxide surface under vacuum, the configurational entropy may be insignificant. In this case, a vibrational analysis (correcting for ZPE and possibly vibrational entropy) at the transition state may be appropriate. The total correction will likely be small in this case.

For a vibrational calculation, you can just use IBRION=-5 and NFREE=2 as shown on the VASPwiki. For the TS, you should get a single nonreal frequency because you're at a saddlepoint. You can use these frequencies to get the ZPE correction and the vibrational entropy from the harmonic oscillator equations. I'll reproduce the harmonic oscillator entropy equation here:
\begin{equation} S = -Nk_{b}(1-e^{-\beta \epsilon }) + Nk_{b}\frac{\beta \epsilon }{e^{\beta \epsilon } -1} \end{equation}

On the other hand, for a molecule in solution or a solvated interface, simple vibrational analysis will not describe the entropy of the system very well. Unless you're willing to use a more advanced sampling method, you may just want to report the enthalpic barrier.

Answer (score 2):

It depends on why you've made the NEB.
If to find a possible reaction coordinate, you can use the ∆E as an indicator.

Another thing is that you can't perform the "traditional" thermochemistry correction (so diagonalizing the Hessian matrix) because you aren't on a stationary point. I know there are some methods, but I'm not an expert on this so unfortunately, I can't help you by pointing out some literature.